# Получение числа подписчиков группы в ВК

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Добрый день! Я пишу приложение с использованием API Вконтакте. Но никак не могу найти метод, который позволил бы получить число подписчиков какой-либо группы. Методы для получения информации о группах почему-то такую информацию не предоставляют. Можно ли как-то узнать число подписчиков произвольной группы? Может я не заметил нужный метод?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пробовали этот метод? 
https://vk.com/dev/groups.getMembers
Он возвращает количество пользователей и сам массив пользователей

Comment: Зачем длину? Там в ответе количество участников отдельным полем идет.

Comment: @tym32167, да точно, не обратил внимания)

Comment: @M.Green .большое спасибо, буду пробовать!

Comment: @Pupkin, если ответ вам помог решить проблему пометьте его, пожалуйста, как верный.